# Iphone VPN security

Tags: iphone, security, vpn

When developing an application, there might come a time where I would want to establish a secure connection like a vpn with a client. An iphone is the topic here. Once the user has established this, is all IP traffic routed when I suggest it do so? I'm curious about some open port or inspection of vpn traffic.

Is there any method available with the SDK to validate that no data has been sent "around" the route that I suppose the switch activates?

The problem is more of a question in the inherent security of the iPhone. If I say that all traffic should go through the vpn I've selected, is there anything buried in the API's or even the SDK that points to the base operating system (osx) being able to talk to another ip address without going through the proxy? If I am at a location using 3G and my app is using VPN to secure data, I have to make sure there is no backdoor or leakage that I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a typical client-server configuration, you should configure the server so that access is only possible via VPN. This means that you can tell if the user is connecting via VPN on the client side, because if they weren't they wouldn't be able to connect.

Other than reachability tests, there's no way of "knowing" if the user is connected via a particular VPN configuration.

Comment: This does raise a good question about making -sure- that we are still connected via VPN. The icon could be done with a jailbroken device, but I am interested in something else.

I need to know that if my users are instructed to go to settings and the VPN, will the iphone continue to talk to push servers, etc, over non secure communication.